# Find databasename in connectionstring using SSIS expression

Tags: ssis, expression, sql-server-2019

I have in SSIS 2019  a projectparameter that contains a connectionstring and has for example the following value:

```
Data Source=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=CoolDatabase;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;
```

Using a SSIS Expression I am trying to exract the string `CoolDatabase` from the projectparameter.

I got this far but then I hit a brick wall...... The probolem is that I do not know how to find the length of the name of the Initial Catalog. IN this case it is 12 but it could be any value really.

```
@[User::databasename]=  SUBSTRING( @[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString] ,
 FINDSTRING( @[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString] ,"Initial Catalog=",1 ) + 16
,12
)
```

How to determine the length of Initial Catalog ? (in this example it is 12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved like this:

1. If you want result only like `CoolDatabase` use this expression:

```
RIGHT(
   LEFT( @[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString], FINDSTRING(@[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString], ";", 2) - 1),
   FINDSTRING( REVERSE(LEFT( @[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString], FINDSTRING(@[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString], ";", 2) - 1)), "=", 1) - 1
)
```

2. If you want result like `Initial Catalog=CoolDatabase` use this:

```
RIGHT(
   LEFT( @[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString], FINDSTRING(@[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString], ";", 2) - 1),
   FINDSTRING( REVERSE(LEFT( @[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString], FINDSTRING(@[$Project::DOELSERVER_ConnectionString], ";", 2) - 1)), ";", 1) - 1
)
```

Only difference between these two codes is `=` in 1st and `;` in 2nd expression at the end.

Comment: I get it. Cool! Thanx!